# Plotting monthly percentages in shiny R

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, shinydashboard

I have a shiny app that has four different plots in a shinydashboard. I want all the plots to be reactive based on a sliderInput for the year. I got this to work perfectly fine... However, I want one of the plots to have months in x-axis, instead of years like the others, but to still be reactive to the year sliderInput and have the dataframe be filtered accordingly. I got this to work as well but I can't seem to figure out how to change the months from being numbers to being the actual months name on the x-axis.

**This is what I want(Not as box plot just want x-axis):**

[image]

**Sample Data:**

```
    df1<-structure(list(stdate = structure(c(16611, 16611, 16611, 16615, 
16615, 16615, 14004, 14004, 14004, 16616, 16616, 16616, 16616, 
16616, 16616, 17485, 17483, 16678, 14000, 14000, 14000, 17211, 
17210, 16615, 16611, 16756, 14098, 16674, 16674, 14096), class = "Date"), 
    sttime = structure(c(37800, 37800, 37800, 35100, 35100, 35100, 
    42600, 42600, 42600, 38700, 38700, 38700, 32400, 32400, 32400, 
    35400, 33000, 49800, 34200, 34200, 34200, 37800, 30600, 35100, 
    37800, 37800, 35400, 37800, 32400, 37200), class = c("hms", 
    "difftime"), units = "secs"), locid = c("USGS-01388500", 
    "USGS-01388500", "USGS-01388500", "USGS-01464585", "USGS-01464585", 
    "USGS-01464585", "USGS-01464515", "USGS-01464515", "USGS-01464515", 
    "USGS-01407330", "USGS-01407330", "USGS-01407330", "USGS-01466500", 
    "USGS-01466500", "USGS-01466500", "USGS-01387500", "USGS-01395000", 
    "USGS-01400860", "USGS-01377000", "USGS-01377000", "USGS-01377000", 
    "USGS-01367625", "USGS-01398000", "USGS-01464585", "USGS-01388500", 
    "USGS-01390630", "USGS-01396090", "USGS-01407810", "USGS-01407821", 
    "USGS-01391540"), charnam = c("Chloride", "Total dissolved solids", 
    "Specific conductance", "Chloride", "Total dissolved solids", 
    "Specific conductance", "Specific conductance", "Total dissolved solids", 
    "Chloride", "Chloride", "Total dissolved solids", "Specific conductance", 
    "Chloride", "Total dissolved solids", "Specific conductance", 
    "Specific conductance", "Specific conductance", "Specific conductance", 
    "Specific conductance", "Total dissolved solids", "Chloride", 
    "Specific conductance", "Specific conductance", "Total dissolved solids", 
    "Total dissolved solids", "Total dissolved solids", "Specific conductance", 
    "Specific conductance", "Specific conductance", "Specific conductance"
    ), val = c(109, 294, 525, 31.9, 119, 184, 226, 155, 33, 36.4, 
    155, 203, 3.38, 43, 41, 674, 466, 312, 540, 328, 105, 844, 
    683, 100, 275, 432, 342, 200, 237, 805), valunit = c("mg/l", 
    "mg/l", "uS/cm @25C", "mg/l", "mg/l", "uS/cm @25C", "uS/cm @25C", 
    "mg/l", "mg/l", "mg/l", "mg/l", "uS/cm @25C", "mg/l", "mg/l", 
    "uS/cm @25C", "uS/cm @25C", "uS/cm @25C", "uS/cm @25C", "uS/cm @25C", 
    "mg/l", "mg/l", "uS/cm @25C", "uS/cm @25C", "mg/l", "mg/l", 
    "mg/l", "uS/cm @25C", "uS/cm @25C", "uS/cm @25C", "uS/cm @25C"
    ), LatDeg = c(40.969722, 40.969722, 40.969722, 40.041667, 
    40.041667, 40.041667, 40.176944, 40.176944, 40.176944, 40.319167, 
    40.319167, 40.319167, 39.885, 39.885, 39.885, 41.098056, 
    40.618889, 40.418333, 40.999167, 40.999167, 40.999167, 41.040278, 
    40.473333, 40.041667, 40.969722, NA, 40.860556, 40.2075, 
    40.211667, 40.867778), LongDeg = c(-74.281944, -74.281944, 
    -74.281944, -74.766944, -74.766944, -74.766944, -74.598889, 
    -74.598889, -74.598889, -74.160556, -74.160556, -74.160556, 
    -74.505278, -74.505278, -74.505278, -74.162778, -74.283333, 
    -74.787222, -73.989167, -73.989167, -73.989167, -74.629722, 
    -74.827778, -74.766944, -74.281944, NA, -74.76, -74.328889, 
    -74.295833, -74.094722), HUC14 = c("HUC02030103110020", "HUC02030103110020", 
    "HUC02030103110020", "HUC02040201100030", "HUC02040201100030", 
    "HUC02040201100030", "HUC02040201060020", "HUC02040201060020", 
    "HUC02040201060020", "HUC02030104070070", "HUC02030104070070", 
    "HUC02030104070070", "HUC02040202030070", "HUC02040202030070", 
    "HUC02040202030070", "HUC02030103100030", "HUC02030104050060", 
    "HUC02030105090020", "HUC02030103170060", "HUC02030103170060", 
    "HUC02030103170060", "HUC02020007010010", "HUC02030105030060", 
    "HUC02040201100030", "HUC02030103110020", NA, "HUC02030105010040", 
    "HUC02030104100010", "HUC02030104100010", "HUC02030103140070"
    ), WMA = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 12L, 
    12L, 12L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 3L, 7L, 10L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 8L, 
    20L, 3L, NA, 8L, 12L, 12L, 4L), year = c(2015, 2015, 2015, 
    2015, 2015, 2015, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 
    2015, 2015, 2017, 2017, 2015, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2017, 2017, 
    2015, 2015, 2015, 2008, 2015, 2015, 2008), month = c(6, 6, 
    6, 6, 6, 6, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 11, 11, 8, 5, 5, 5, 
    2, 2, 6, 6, 11, 8, 8, 8, 8)), .Names = c("stdate", "sttime", 
"locid", "charnam", "val", "valunit", "LatDeg", "LongDeg", "HUC14", 
"WMA", "year", "month"), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

**What I have tried:**

```
parameters<-unique(df1$charnam)


sidebar<-dashboardSidebar(
  selectInput("parameter_input","Select Parameter",
              parameters,selected = "Chloride"),
  sliderInput("date","Select Year Range",
              min = min(df1$year),
              max = max(df1$year),
              value = c(min,max),
              sep = "",
              step = 1)
)
header<-dashboardHeader()
body<- dashboardBody(
          box(plotOutput("plot1")))

ui<-dashboardPage(header=header,
                  sidebar = sidebar,
                  body = body)



server<- function(input,output,session){

  month_percent_over<-reactive({
      df1%>%
        filter(charnam == input$parameter_input)%>%
        mutate(val = as.numeric(val),greater = val >230) %>%
        group_by(month,year) %>%
        summarize(n_greater = sum(greater),percentage=mean(greater)*100)%>%
        filter(year >= input$date[1])%>%
        filter(year <= input$date[2])

  }) 




### Creates % > Standard month plots ###
output$plot1<- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data = month_percent_over(),aes(x=month,y = percentage))+
      geom_point(aes(colour="blue"),size=3,stat = "identity")+
      geom_smooth(method = "lm", se=FALSE,linetype = "dashed",aes(y=percentage,colour="red"))+
      scale_color_manual("",
                         #breaks= c("per"),
                         values = c("blue","red"),
                         labels=c("% Samples > Standard","Trendline"),
                         guide=guide_legend(override.aes=list(linetype=c(0,2), lwd=c(3,0.5))))+
      scale_x_discrete(labels=c("1" = "January", "2" = "Feburary",
                                "3" = "March","4"="April","5"="May",
                                "6"="June","7"="July",
                                "8"="August","9"="September","10"="October",
                                "11"="November","12"="December"))


})
}
shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: FYI that’s not correct spelling of February. Anyway try using formatting the date value with the format string for full spelling of month.

Comment: @42- Whoops typo .. thanks for pointing that out. Being that I am fairly new to R, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: The argument to labels might be ‘format(stdate, %B)’.  Not tested since R doesn’t run on my cellphone.

Comment: Where would I put that?

Comment: seems like you are plotting the "val" on your Y-axis. If you summarize, the "val" column of data is removed. you may need to create another reactive dataframe with that column present. Then, you need to specify that dataframe as your data in ggplot to plot the boxplots.

also do x=as.factor(as.character(month)) to convert from numeric to a factor for boxplot

Comment: @user8383881 No I am plotting "percentage" on Y-Axis.

Comment: your sample code runs with the word "month" as your x-axis.

Comment: Yeah I want the different months on the x-axis and for the plot to be reactive if user changes the years on sliderInput. I want the month's on the x-axis to be static.

Comment: so if there's no data for a particular month, you still want to show empty for that month?

Comment: my apologies.. in my real app it doesn't do that because my data has all the months.